# Non-credit in Julie and Julia

Tags: credits, julie-and-julia

I've read other threads regarding credit/non-credit in movies, but haven't come across my particular question.  I was watching "Julie and Julia" last night and noticed something odd about the credits.  There were credits given for the "Houghton Mifflin Executive" (3 of them) but no credit was given for the "Knopf executives" of which there were at least 2.  One of them, a woman, had several scenes including one with Streep where they come up with the name of the book.  It is a much bigger part than many others that were credited.  She doesn't appear in the original movie credits or in IMDB, unless I'm missing something, which is also possible.  She isn't a big star, so those reasons for non-credit don't apply, and her role was bigger than others who were credited.  Any idea?

Comment: It is possible they have actual names. Are you sure that they aren't credited?

Comment: If you can post images of the people you're thinking about, it might help. I haven't seen the film since it was released so I don't know which actors you mean.  My guess, though, is that they're supposed to represent specific people, and were given their names as credits.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of a photo, Catija.  I looked around and found a full length movie on Youtube.  I found the scene, and the first Knopf executive is not credited, although you barely if at all see his face.  The other one IS credited as Judith. as in Judith Jones.  I guess I should have known how famous she is in the book world...  So the actress turns out to be Erin Dilly.  Whew!  Now I can sleep at night!

Thanks for your help!
Da

Comment: Glad you found it!  You should answer your own question so that it's on record as being solved!

Answer (score 1):

The face of the first Knopf executive was never shown clearly, and so probably did not get a credit.  The second executive, with a much greater role, was credited by name as Judith Jones.